# Firebase realtime database rules for chat app for 2 nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My Chat and Friends node are separate of course, so would it be possible to refer to the friend node when writing rules for my Chat.

my current chat rules are as follows:

```
"Chats": {
        "$uid_1":{
          "$uid_2":{
           ".read": "auth.uid == $uid_1  || auth.uid == $uid_2", 
           ".write": "auth.uid == $uid_1  || auth.uid == $uid_2 "
          }
        }
    },
```

Friends structure in database

```
 - Friends

      -uid1
         -uid2
             - username


        -uid2
           -uid1
              - username
```

when users are no longer friends, how do I make sure that messages do not go through? I have rules inside my android application but was told that I should write it in the security rules too.

Comment: How are you storing these "friendships"?

Comment: The structure? I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check data anywhere in the database, by starting from the [`root` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#root).

So if you want to only allow `uid2` to write to `uid1`'s messages if their UID is stored under `uid1`'s friend list, you can check:

```
".write": "(auth.uid == $uid_1  || auth.uid == $uid_2) 
           && root.child('Friends').child($uid_1).child($uid_2).exists()"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "chats": {
      "$uid": {
        "$uid2": {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.uid === $uid2",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid && root.child('friends').child($uid).child($uid2).exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will still keep READ access for both the users but they cannot write new messages.

Though your db structure looks a bit difficult to store messages. `chats -> uid 1 -> uid2` won't be same always I believe or at least it will be difficult for you to maintain the order like which user remains 1st and so.